# Jquery On Events only if both are allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a query on event fire if the field is validated and paste. This fire functions if the paste or the success.field.fv are correct. Is there a way if only both are correct?

```
.on('paste success.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            if($("#bin_or_part").val() == ''){
                $("#bin_or_part").focus();
            } else{
                 $("#barcode").focus();   
            }
    });
```

and I tired:

```
.on('paste', function(e, data) {
        on('success.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            if($("#bin_or_part").val() == ''){
                $("#bin_or_part").focus();
            } else{
                 $("#barcode").focus();   
            }
         });
    });
```

Comment: can you share js fidder ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qfx19yhq/

Comment: Correct. After Paste I Want it validated. The Validator is another function. On success it fires the event success.field.fv but I only want to fire the on success if it was as paste.

Comment: How would two events get triggered at the same time? If you want one to happen than the other to happen either bind the new event listener or use "flags" aka booleans to set the state.

Comment: the sucess validator event is a custom event and it triggerred only if the jquery returns true on validation. it check for validation onchange. but is there a way to detect if the input was a paste?